# Отсутствие подключения к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, только начал программировать на `php`.
Установил `Apache + php, MySql`. Подключился к серверу через `Devart MySql` и создал базу.
Скрипты `php` работают, а подключиться к базе -не могу - даже не выводит что ошибка- просто белый экран. 
Код:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="Roman";
$pwd="11111";
$db="MySQLDB";
    echo $host." ".$user." ".$pwd." ".$db;

$link=@mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd,$db);
if ( !$link ) {
  echo "Could not connect: " . mysql_error();
} else {
  echo "Connect OK.";
}
?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело, т.к. гугл не помог- беру копирую все примеры и вижу белый экран, такое впечатление что он не знает функции `mysql_connect`, хотя в `php.ini` раскомментированы библиотеки для работы с  `MySQL`.

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Все походу проигнорировали комментарий @eicto :(

Comment: я сделал с примером mysqli_connect() - всёравно белый экран.

Answer (score 3):

"даже не выводит что ошибка" - а зачем тогда @ поставили? может он и блокирует ошибку?

Comment: Пишет Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\Apache\htdocs\1.php on line 8
Я не пойму, чего он не найдёт библиотеку. В php.ini раскомментировано extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
в httpd.conf написано PHPIniDir "C:\php5\;C:\php5\ext\;"

Comment: может он вообще к этому ini не обращается?

Answer (score 3):

Убедись, что у тебя создан пользователь "Roman" и БД называется так же, как указано в переменной $dbname.

```
    $sqlhost = "localhost";   
    $dbname = "MySQLDB";   
    $sqluser = "Roman";   
    $sqlpass = "11111";

    $dbcnx = mysql_connect($sqlhost, $sqluser, $sqlpass);   
    if (!$dbcnx) {   
    echo "<p>К сожалению, не доступен сервер MySQL</p>";   
    exit();   
    }   
    if (!mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbcnx) ) {   
    echo "<p>К сожалению, не доступна база данных</p>";   
    exit();   
    }
```

Comment: Он ругается Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
Думаю, должен был бы выдать что база не доступна, а он вообще не понимает ни mysql_connect ни mysqli_connect. Такое впечатление что библиотеки не подключены

Answer (score 0):

Есть одно правильное действие, которое нужно с самого начала выполнить, а именно создать `php`-файл с кодом

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Затем выполнить через вызов в `URL`. Там будет написано все, включая даже то, какой `php.ini` файл используется. Сдается мне, у тебя много серверов проинсталлированы на компе, - чинишь ты один, а запросы другой перехватывает.

И еще: есть такие файлы - `access.log` и `error.log` - они лежат в папке `apache/logs`. Просмотри их внимательно на предмет загрузки модулей и ошибок. Только убедись сначала, что ищешь в *правильном* `Apache`.